# Create a "random" number between range without any module except time

Tags: python, random, time, range, generator

I would like to create myself a "random" number generator of integers between 2 edges. Moreover, I would like to create the same thing but with float numbers between two edges (like the random.random but of the range I want).

Time is required for me for timestamps.

I am currently learning the way random numbers are generated (I am using this way with timestamp as a start):

```
a = int
b = int
m = int
number = time.mktime (time.localtime ())

for x in range (0, m):
    number = (a*number + c) % m
    print (number)
```

(int can be any integer number. There are multiple ways to optimize the returned values (to long to explain here))

This is the way I've learnt to have "random" integers. I am currently searching for a way to solve the problem above using this way (if possible). Any ideas?

Comment: Use two int A and B and then you can do A + float("0."+ str(B)) (ok it's dirty but like a random generator with date...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're always taking your number modulo `m`, `m` is the maximum value of the result. Also, finding a random number between `min` and `max` is the same as finding a random number between 0 and `max - min`, and adding `min` to that.

```
def rand_range(min, max, a, b, n):
    m = max - min
    number = time.mktime (time.localtime ())

    for x in range (0, m):
        number = (a*number + b) % m

    return number + min
```

To get a floating point number out of this, you can use the function above to define:

```
def rand_range_float(min, max, density, a, b, n):
    rand_int = rand_range(0, density, a, b, n)
    return min + (float(rand_int)/density)*(max-min)
```

In this function, `density` specifies how many possible floating point values you want. For example, if you'd call `rand_range_float(0, 1, 2, a, b, c)`, the function could return 2 possible values; 0.0 or 0.5

Comment: Thanks a lot just what I needed!

Comment: What is the use of the n variable in the two functions though?

Comment: Oh, I misread your question slightly, and I just opied your code for the loop. I thought there was a variable `n` to define the number of iterations, but you're just using `m` there, so you can leave out the `n` argument.